# Creating a new Laravel project with the Laravel Installer gives an error because of Symfony

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, zsh, psr-4

I have just installed composer to start learning Laravel but I have already encountered an annoying problem. When I run `laravel new example-project` on zsh, it seems that it has a big problem with Symfony:
[image]

It is a lot of lines but it seems it is all related to Class Symfony\Component\Translation* and the psr-4 autoloading standard. I have searched online but to no avail, seems like a unique problem.

My PATHs

/usr/local/bin

/usr/bin

/bin

/usr/sbin

/sbin

/Users/USERNAME/.composer/vendor/bin

Additionally, the command ends with this message: **Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1**

Comment: Propably the same fix as for my error. 
Rollback to "symfony/translation": "v5.3.7",
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69359403/laravel-symfony-arrayloader-not-found

Comment: This should be fix now with a new minor release 5.3.9 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/43212#issuecomment-929029937